# How firestore logging works?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore references, a method is given as

```
public static void setLoggingEnabled (boolean loggingEnabled)
```

And in its description given
"Globally enables/disables Firestore logging for the SDK"

I don't understand what it means by global here, because I am already able to add failure listeners and add logs

Will it sends logs directly to firebase Crashlytics or

Logs will be saved on all devices which uses my app or

Will it be only visible in my android studio logs?

Should I enable this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling this logging will write additional information to the logcat output of your app on things like wire traffic (so the data that goes over the wire), encoding an decoding of the data, and much more. This sort of information is typically used for troubleshooting problems in the implementation. No information is sent to Crashlytics, nor are these logs automatically saved anywhere.

Comment: So who will be able to access that information, me , Firebase or anyone can?

Comment: Anyone with access to the device. The logging is not sent to Firebase's (nor anyone else's) servers. I'm a bit clear what you're trying to accomplish here though. It seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us what goal you have in mind with enabling this logging?

Comment: "Anyone with access to the device", That's I am looking for because I don't want to enable anything which helps other user to see my logs or may compromise my apps security